# storm localcluster could not load Bolt

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I'm trying to debug very simple topology (1 spout 1 bolt)

```
public class JoinerTopologyTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setNumWorkers(5);
    conf.setDebug(true);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("SPOUT-1",new MySpout(),1);
    builder.setBolt("BOLT-1",new Bolt1(), 3)
            .shuffleGrouping("SPOUT-1");
    //builder.setBolt("JOINER", new JoinerBolt(),1)
    //        .shuffleGrouping("BOLT-1")
    //        .shuffleGrouping("SPOUT-1","str1");

    final LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("TOPO1",conf,builder.createTopology());


    System.in.read();

    cluster.shutdown();
}
```

}

But when i run it from InteliJ IDEA i get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pixonic.zephyr.compaction.tests.Bolt1
>       at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.javaDeserialize(Utils.java:181) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>       at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:430) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]

and

> [Thread-15] ERROR o.a.s.d.worker - Error on initialization of server mk-worker
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.daemon.acker
>       at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.javaDeserialize(Utils.java:181) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>       at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:430) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]

but same topology runs well in Cluster mode. 
PS in my pom.xml in debug mode i have:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
>         <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.1</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
> ```

**EDIT**

project to reproduce bug: https://github.com/holinov/storm-101-localcluster/tree/master

Comment: Why do you put "solved" and not actually answer the question by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting it here as asked in comments

**SOLVED**

To run or debug Topology in IDEA don't use maven runner.
Just right click on topology class and choose Debug->JoinerTopologyTest...main() that does not have MVN icon